# Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight how to make only one supported orientation

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, screen-orientation

I want to get app with only one support orientation. It means, that i want only

```
LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight
```

I don`t want both. But

```
SupportedOrientations
```

allows only 3 modes Landscape, Portrait or both.
How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't force LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight, you'll have to hack it.

You can give the appearance of only one orientation by rotating the whole page by 180 degrees on orientation change.  I would just use a `RenderTransform` at LayoutRoot, and set its rotation to 180 in the [orientation change handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207002(v=vs.105).aspx).  Eg:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft))
        rotateTransform.Angle = 0;
    else if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Portrait) == (PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft))
        rotateTransform.Angle = 180;
}
```

Your XAML would be something like:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"> 
   <Grid.RenderTransform> 
       <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
   </Grid.RenderTransform>
   <!-- ... -->
</Grid>
```